# State object in useLocation() - ReactRouterDom in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-router-dom

In React router dom, there's a state object in useLocation()

```
const { state } = useLocation()
```

How do I get the same object but in NextJS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useRouter()` in next.js ([Next.js document](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router))

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

  ...
  const router = useRouter();

  ...
  <div
    onClick={() => router.push({
      pathname: "/",
      query: {
        key: "value", // use "query" instead of "state"
      },
    },
    "/" // hide query from url
  )}>
```

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

  ...
  const { query } = useRouter();
  console.log(query); // {key: 'value'}
```

Comment: I'm using Link so is it like this?:
`
<Link
      className={styles.longtext}
      href={`/${category}/${encodeURIComponent(text)}`}
     >
      <a
       onClick={() =>
        router.push(
         {
          pathname: `/${category}/${encodeURIComponent(text)}`,
          query: {
           key: 'value', // use "query" instead of "state"
          },
         },
         '/' // hide query from url
        )
       }
      >
       {alttext ? alttext : text}
      </a>
     </Link>
`f

Comment: @tadS If you use <Link>,  try this !
<Link href={{ pathname: "/", query: { key: "value" }}}> <a> ... </a></Link>

Comment: @tadS In addition, If you use "as", you can hide the query from the url
<Link href={{ pathname: "/", query: { key: "value" }} as="/"}> <a> ... </a></Link>

Comment: What does the State in useLocation() represent for?

Comment: @tadS The State of useLocation() represents the information passed through useNavigate() or Link in React when moving the page.