# What re-places useLocation() in react-router-dom from Next.js next/navigation?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-router-dom

Recently, I migrated from React to Next.js version@14.0.4. In my website, I used states while pushing using useNavigate() and take value from another page using useLocation(). How can I do same thing in Next.js
I am doing with query thing in Next.js but it is visible in link above, I even learned how to hide it but I cannot receive state from params anymore.

I tried lots of things and one example is here: [link related to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74176295/state-object-in-uselocation-reactrouterdom-in-nextjs)
In here it says to use next/router, but in next.js version 14.0.4 says to use only next/navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Migrating from `next.router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#migrating-from-nextrouter)

- The `useRouter` hook should be imported from `next/navigation` and not `next/router` when using the App Router
- The `pathname` string has been removed and is replaced by `usePathname()`
- The `query` object has been removed and is replaced by `useSearchParams()`
- `router.events` has been replaced. [See below](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#router-events).

Follow the link/navigating part of the linked [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758812/next-js-keep-the-state-or-send-props-when-router-push) of the post you linked to, but follow the instructions above to use the correct `useRouter`, `usePathname`, and `useSearchParams` hooks if you are opting in to the new behavior in the `app` directory.

Example:

```js
'use client'

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

...

const router = useRouter();

...

router.push("/somepath?param1=foo");
```

```js
'use client'

import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

...

const searchParams = useSearchParams();
const param1 = searchParams.get("param1"); // "foo"
```

Comment: thank you very much, but is there a way to hide params from url but still get it from searchParams?

Comment: @AbdulazizSultonmurodov Yes, it appears the [`push`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/src/shared/lib/router/router.ts#L1025) method takes several arguments, the second of which is an `as?: URL` value. Something like `router.push("/terminal_summary?param1=foo", "/terminal_summary");` looks like it should work.

Comment: That did not work, because I think previous versions it had, but after version Next.js 14, they removed

Comment: @AbdulazizSultonmurodov Are you sure? I pulled that from, and linked to, the current `push` method source code, which is Next.js v14 (14.0.5). What specific version of Next.js are you using? If it doesn't work then maybe they did remove this functionality from the `router` object (*but that doesn't appear to be the case*).

Comment: I am using vesrion@14.0.4, here what router.push accepts in doc:
router.push(href: string, { scroll: boolean })
So only href I can give, no other paramaters

Comment: @AbdulazizSultonmurodov Shoot, you're right... I linked to the other `useRouter` interface. Here's the `next/navigation` `useRouter` app router [`push`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/src/shared/lib/app-router-context.shared-runtime.ts#L124C40-L124C40) method declaration. Looks like it doesn't have the capability to "mask" the search params unfortunately, which is a bit of a bummer.

Comment: yeah that is why did not find anything related to it, then I am just adding my states to the query